# How to check and change the values in an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on a very simple tic tac toe project where I check if a user input is in an array (looking for an integer from 1 to 9) and, if not, I want to change an index to that user input. Below is code, don't know what I'm doing wrong. CallSquare() returns an int.

```
        int [] numbersPlayed = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int callResult;
        int totalPlayed = 0;

        while (totalPlayed != 10)
        {
            
            callResult = CallSquare();
        
            foreach (int i in numbersPlayed)
            {
                if (numbersPlayed.Contains(callResult))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nError, number already in array");
                    break;
                }

                else 
                {
                    numbersPlayed.SetValue(callResult, i);
                }
        
            }

            totalPlayed++;
        }
```

Basically, what it does after input is giving me the Error message above, even though I type an integer between 1 and 9, and then, only changes the value in the index number I have entered on the first input (for example, if I enter 1 on the first input, it will only change the first index on following inputs). Help please?

**Edit: what I'm trying to do is to keep a record of the numbers that have been played. I figured an array like that was the way to go, but if you have a better solution, I'm listening.**

Comment: BTW: From experience, it is safer in such cases to use `while ( totalPlayed < 10 )`.

Comment: I am still having trouble figuring out, what your code is _supposed_ to do. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sure thing: the user inputs a number between 1 and 9. I want to check if the number is in the array. If it is: error message. If it's not, then the number is stored in the array. That's why I populate the array with zeros, so I just change the value with whatever number is input. And start again.

Comment: First of all, in general, it is not a good idea to mutate the collection you are iterating. Then, maybe step it through. I really think the code is not doing what you think it should. If you input "1" in first iteration of the while, "1" will be put at index 0 **10 times**. Now in second iteration, if you input for example "2", Index 0 = 1, so "2" will be put in index 1, then "2" will put in index 2, then "2" will be put in index 0 for 7 times . ... ( stepped through in head, but that's what *I* think will happen).

Comment: ^^ I made a mistake ... give me a sec.

Comment: That is almost exactly what's happening, I think I'm just too tired to see it through now. Also, just beginning with arrays, not familiar with how to manipulate them yet.

Comment: Have a look at this output : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZmNsMz Maybe it's clearer then.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using and appending to a list.

Comment: Yep, I see it. Thanks for the clarification, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you'd be better off using a `List`:

```
List<int> numbersPlayed = new List<int>();
int callResult;
int totalPlayed = 0;

while (totalPlayed < 10)
{
    
    callResult = CallSquare();

    if( numbersPlayed.Contains(callResult) )
    {
         Console.WriteLine("\n\nError, number already in array");
    }
    else
    {
          numbersPlayed.Add(callResult);
    }

    totalPlayed++;
}
```

Comment: Yep, definitely better way to go. Thanks for the feedback mate